# jQuery Sortable duplicating dropped item in origin list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got 2 `sortable()` elements on a page, `.draggable_to` and `.elements_draggable`. The latter being elements which I can drag to the former.

Here is the code which initializes these:

```
$('.draggable_to').sortable({
    update: function (e, ui) {              
        if(ui.sender) {
            var dropped_elem = $(ui.sender.children()[0].innerHTML);
            var html = self.generateElementHTML(dropped_elem.attr('data-type'));
            ui.item.html(html);
        }
        ui.sender.data('copied', true);
    }
});
$('.elements_draggable').parent().sortable({
    placeholder: 'ui secondary segment green',
    connectWith: '.draggable_to',
    helper: function (e, li) {
        this.copyHelper = li.clone().insertAfter(li);
        $(this).data('copied', false);
        return li.clone();
    },
    start: function(e, ui) {
        ui.placeholder.html("Add new " + ui.helper[0].innerText + " element.");
    }
});
```

When something is dragged from `.elements_draggable` and dragged to `.draggable_to`, the original element should be *duplicated*, then I replace said duplicated element with some custom html generated from `generateElementHTML()`.

This works, but I'm having a problem with the `.elements_draggable` list. For some reason, when I start to drag something from `.elements_draggable`, I'm able to *place* that element back into the same list, duplicating it in the process.

Here is some pictures which I hope illustrates what I mean exactly.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Note: I am aware of the `containment` option, but I don't want to use it for 2 reasons:

- I do not like the way it behaves. It's very jarring to the user.
- It causes a problem where I'm not able to add things to the bottom of the `.draggable_to` list after a couple of elements are added.

How can I prevent dragged elements from duplicating into the same list they were dragged out of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by changing my list of draggable objects to jquery-ui's `draggable()` instead of `sortable()`.

```
$('.draggable_to').sortable({
    update: function (e, ui) {              
        var dropped_elem_type = ui.item.attr('data-type');          
        var html = self.generateElementHTML(dropped_elem_type);     
        ui.item.attr('style', null);
        ui.item.html(html);
    }
});
$('.draggable_element').draggable({
    connectToSortable: '.draggable_to',
    helper: "clone",
});
```